# How to custom sort in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In MYSQL I can do:

```
Select Name, Sum (A) as total_A, Sum(B) as total_B, Sum (A) / Sum(B) as C 
From table 
Where ... 
Group by Name 
order by C ASC
```

How I can sort with ES like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Sort functionality as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

from the documentation:

> Allows to add one or more sort on specific fields. Each sort can be
>   reversed as well. The sort is defined on a per field level, with
>   special field name for _score to sort by score, and _doc to sort by
>   index order.

```
{
    "sort" : [
        { "post_date" : {"order" : "asc"}},
        "user",
        { "name" : "desc" },
        { "age" : "desc" },
        "_score"
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really write ạnd run this code. I try search some topic and hopeless. ES not allow like this :sosad: